# create launcher in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and have installed Eclipse (as I am into Android coding). I downloaded the tar.gz file for eclipse and unpacked into a folder on my file system. Now everytime I need to go to that folder and run the executable unlike the other applications that I start using the dash board (just by typing there name). How can I make the eclipse executable list on my Dashboard?

I have heard of one possible solution - create a launcher icon on the desktop for eclipse. But on the latest release of ubuntu there is no such option. How do I go about this if it is the only solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/q/64222/46531

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop. Ubuntu 12.04 uses Gnome 3 and does not include `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, so the other question and certainly its answer do not apply.